# How to solve this limit : $\lim\limits_{b\to a}\frac{be^{ac+ax}-ae^{bc+bx}}{e^{ac+ax}-e^{bc+bx}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

how do i solve

$$\lim_{b\to a}\frac{be^{ac+ax}-ae^{bc+bx}}{e^{ac+ax}-e^{bc+bx}}$$

**edit:** i see, i was just derivating on wrong variable

Comment: $x$ is fixed. You are supposed to differentiate w.r.t. $b$, not w.r.t. $x$.

Comment: oh, you right, i was dumb lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{b\to a}\frac{be^{ac+ax}-ae^{bc+bx}}{e^{ac+ax}-e^{bc+bx}}$$

Let $b=a+h$

$$\lim_{b\to a}\frac{be^{ac+ax}-ae^{bc+bx}}{e^{ac+ax}-e^{bc+bx}}=\lim_{b\to a}\frac{h+a(1-e^{hc+hx})}{1-e^{hc+hx}}=\lim_{b\to a}a+\frac{h}{-hc-hx}=a-{1\over x+c}$$

This one is without L'hopital using the expansion of $e^x$

Answer (score 2):

derivating on right variable lead easy to the answer

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{b\to a}\frac{be^{ac+ax}-ae^{bc+bx}}{e^{ac+ax}-e^{bc+bx}} &= \lim_{b\to a}\frac{e^{ac+ax}-a(c+x)e^{bc+bx}}{-(c+x)e^{bc+bx}}\\
&= \frac{e^{ac+ax}-a(c+x)e^{ac+ax}}{-(c+x)e^{ac+ax}}\\
&= \frac{e^{ac+ax}(1-a(c+x))}{-(c+x)e^{ac+ax}}\\
&= \frac{a(c+x)-1}{c+x}
\end{align}$$